# Find Jordan form of matrix with parameter $m\in\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

the (real) matrix is $\left[ \begin{matrix} 0& 0& 0\\ 1& 0& -m^{2}\\0& 1& m\\\end{matrix} \right]$.
Well, the characteristic polynomial is $p(t)=t(t^2-mt+m^2)$ so it doesn't have any real roots except 0, and then I got stuck.

Comment: You have one real and two imaginary eigenvalues - so nothing is different because we have three unique eigenvalues, thus the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Moo Unless $m=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Good point!

Comment: @Moo if it's diagonalizable so there is no Jordan form, and if $m=0$ then the minimalistic polynomial is $t^2$ and I can use the theorem to show the Jordan form, am I right?

Comment: @Moo yes, the diagonal form is a special JNF case, I guess

Comment: See the examples of Jordan forms on page 5 and non-examples on page 6: http://www.ms.uky.edu/~lee/amspekulin/jordan_canonical_form.pdf - also see Example 2 on the bottom of page 6 for all the flavors of JNFs for a $3x3$ matrix

Comment: @Moo that's a great paper, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case in which $m \neq 0$, the matrix has three distinct eigenvalues.  So, the Jordan form is just the diagonal matrix with those eigenvalues on the diagonal.

For the case in which $m = 0$, we note that transposing the matrix produces a Jordan-form matrix.  Any matrix is similar to its transpose.